# Riemann surface of hyperbolic type.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

We know that a Riemann surface is a connected Haurdorff space with affine charts.

I want to know precisely the definition of a Riemann surface of hyperbolic type. A name of reference is also much appreciated.

Comment: No, this is incorrect definition of a (connected) Riemann surface: What you want to assume is that transition maps are biholomorphic, **not affine**.

Answer (score 1):

A Riemann surface $S$ is **hyperbolic** if its Euler characteristic $\chi(S)$ is negative. In the compact (i.e. without boundary) case, this is equivalent to $S$ having genus $g(S) \ge 2$. This should be discussed in Forster's *Lectures on Riemann Surfaces,* and if not in Jost's *Compact Riemann Surfaces* or Ahlfors & Serio's *Riemann Surfaces*.

Comment: This is correct for Riemann surfaces of finite type. Otherwise, the standard definition is to require the universal covering to be biholomorphic to the unit disk.

Comment: Yes precisely; the maps will be biholomorphic